# Python: rdkit library missing many functions

Tags: python, pycharm, rdkit

I recently installed rdkit on pycharm by first using an anaconda environment, installing rdkit using conda install -c rdkit rdkit, and lastly shifting the installed lib package folder to the anaconda environment that my pycharm uses.

My pycharm can detect that is an rdkit library imported as I can type the following statement and it suggests a list of possible functions.

```
from rdkit import chem
chem.(suggested list appears)
```

However, the suggested list is missing many important functions which is in the rdkit documentation, such as rdkit.chem.Molfromsmiles.
Is it because I have to do the proper installation listen on the rdkit website (http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html)?
I am not sure how to do those on pycharm and any help is appreciated!

Comment: "shifting the installed lib package folder to the anaconda environment" - why would you do it like that? Simply install it in the correct env directly. Also: Have you checked if you can still use the functions missing from the suggestions? Might be that pycharm cannot detect the whole list correctly

Comment: I tried and it says that the reference cannot be found

Comment: Have you installed `rdkit` into the correct environment already?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but how do you install it into the correct environment? Because after typing the -conda install command, it automatically installs rdkit folder to this directory (C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages) and I am created an anaconda environment in pycharm in which the folders for site packages are in C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\kz\Lib\site-packages). So I dragged the file from the former to the later folder.

Comment: type `activate kz` in your terminal before doing the `conda install`